# concatenation of distinct substrings

Tags: java, string, out-of-memory, substring, concatenation

question - Arrange all the distinct substrings of a given string in lexicographical order and concatenate them. Print the Kth character of the concatenated string. It is assured that given value of K will be valid i.e. there will be a Kth character

Input Format 
First line will contain a number T i.e. number of test cases. 
First line of each test case will contain a string containing characters (a−z) and second line will contain a number K.

Output Format 
Print Kth character ( the string is 1 indexed )

Constraints 
1≤T≤5 
1≤length≤105 
K will be an appropriate integer.

Sample Input #00

```
1
dbac
3
```

Sample Output #00

```
c
```

Explanation #00

The substrings when arranged in lexicographic order are as follows

a, ac, b, ba, bac, c, d, db, dba, dbac
On concatenating them, we get

aacbbabaccddbdbadbac
The third character in this string is c and hence the answer.

This is my code :

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Solution 
{

public static void gen(String str,int k)
{


      int i,c;ArrayList<String>al=new ArrayList<String>();
     for(c=0;c<str.length();c++)
    {
        for(i=1;i<=str.length()-c;i++)
        {
            String sub = str.substring(c,c+i);
            al.add(sub);
        }
    }

    HashSet hs = new HashSet();
    hs.addAll(al);
    al.clear();
    al.addAll(hs);

    String[] res = al.toArray(new String[al.size()]); 
    Arrays.sort(res);

    StringBuilder sb= new StringBuilder();

        for(String temp:res)
        {
           sb.append(temp);   
        }

    String s = sb.toString();
    System.out.println(s.charAt(k-1));
}


public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
    int t = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());

        while((t--)>0)
        {
            String str = sc.nextLine();
            int k = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());                 
            gen(str,k);

        }

   }
 }
```

This code worked well for small inputs like for above test case but for large input's it either times out or shows something like this i do understand that problem is with memory , any alternate method to do this question or anyway to reuse the same memory??

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(Arrays.java:2694)
at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:203)
at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1913)
at Solution.gen(Solution.java:19)
at Solution.main(Solution.java:54)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the constraints you are given (up to 105 characters) you shouldn't be having out-of-memory problems. Perhaps you were testing with very big strings.

So in case you have, here are some places where you are wasting memory:

- After you fill the set, you copy it to your list. This means two copies of the collection of substrings, while you are not going to use the set any more.
- After you copy the list to an array, you now have three copies of the collection of substrings, although you are not going to use the list anymore.
- Now you create a `StringBuilder` and put all the substrings into it. But it's not really interesting to know the entire concatenated string. We only need one character in it, so why put the concatenation in memory at all? In addition, in all the wasteful copies above, at least you didn't duplicate the substrings themselves. But now that you are appending them to the `StringBuilder`, you are creating a duplicate of them. And that's going to be a very long string.
- And then you copy the `StringBuilder`'s content to a new string by using `toString()`. This creates a copy of the very large concatenated string (which we already said we don't actually need).

You already got a sound advice of using a `TreeSet` and filling it directly rather than creating a list, a set, and a sorted list. The next step is to extract the correct character from that set *without actually keeping the concatenated string around*.

So, assuming your set is called `set`:

```
Iterator<String> iter = set.iterator();

int lengthSoFar = 0;
String str = null;

while ( lengthSoFar < k && iter.hasNext() ) {

     str = iter.next();           // Got the next substring;
     lengthSoFar += str.length();
}

// At this point we have the substring where we expect the k'th
// character to be.

System.out.println( str.charAt( k - lengthSoFar + str.length() - 1 );
```

Note that it will take the program longer to get to high values of `k` than low values, but generally it will be faster than building the whole concatenated string, because you'll stop as soon as you get to the correct substring.

Answer (score 1):

You are running out of memory. You can increase the memory that the JVM is using by using starting the JVM with -Xms256m -Xmx1024 and you can try some optimizations.

```
public static void gen(String str, int k) {

    int i, c;

    //Adding directly to the Set prevents a larger list because you remove the duplicates
    Set<String> set = new TreeSet<String>();

    for (c = 0; c < str.length(); c++) {
        for (i = 1; i <= str.length() - c; i++) {
            String sub = str.substring(c, c + i);
            set.add(sub);
        }
    }
    //TreeSet already orders by the String comparator


    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    for (String temp : set) {
        sb.append(temp);
        if(sb.length()>k){
           break;
        }
    }

    String s = sb.toString();
    System.out.println(s.charAt(k - 1));
}
```

[EDIT] Added small performance boost. Try it to see if it gets faster or not, I did not look at the performance of StringBuilder.length() to see if it will improve or decrease.

Comment: even after using this code it took more than 4 seconds to compile , so test cases were not passed , but still tanks for this code i do not need to add them to list and hashset and no need to sort... i could directly use set :)

Comment: So my answer is correct. Maybe not enough for programming contest were you are using but is correct. Right?

Comment: Yes , but unfortunately it could not help me to pass the test cases